# What is the nature of impermanence, desire and anatman?

Tags: enlightenment, anatman, impermanence

If everything in unstable, unsatisfying and out of control then what is the point in living? Isn't the 'point of life' meant to be a journey to stability, satisfaction and self control? Thanks :).

Comment: You can't stop the waves but you can learn how to surf!

Comment: ahhh yes Jon Kabat Zinn is a great teacher :D

Comment: Actually it was said by a Hindu swami touring America in the sixties, but JKZ had made it popular for this generation.

Comment: oh I didn't know that, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't the 'point of life' meant to be a journey to stability,
>   satisfaction and self control?

There's no "meant to be" in life. It's not written in the stars that you must do this or that. But you can follow the noble 8 fold path and attain stability and satisfaction while you live.

> If everything in unstable, unsatisfying and out of control

Everything is uncontrollable, but not unstable and unsatisfying. Only conditioned things are unstable and unsatisfying.

Answer (score 3):

Living is a consequence of birth. Everything is unstable, unsatisfying and out of control because of birth.

Birth is a consequence of not knowing what is suffering, what is the cause of suffering, what is the end of suffering and what is the way leading to the end of suffering.

> If everything in unstable, unsatisfying and out of control then what is the point in living?

The point in living is to learn what is suffering, what is the cause of suffering, what is the end of suffering and what is the way leading to the end of suffering.

> Isn't the 'point of life' meant to be a journey to stability, satisfaction and self control?

Thus, you are right in saying: that the 'point of life' is meant to be a journey to stability, satisfaction and self control.

Once you realize what is suffering, what is the cause of suffering, what is the end of suffering and what is the way leading to the end of suffering, you will enjoy the fruits of your realizations in this very same life - you will live a stable and satisfactory life, with no ill will, anger, sadness, fears, greed, hatred, envy, any kind of emotional negativity, etc.

Once you realize what is suffering, what is the cause of suffering, what is the end of suffering and what is the way leading to the end of suffering, you will live a life completely devoid of any kind of suffering and your death will be completely devoid of any kind of suffering. After death, you'll not be born again - you will be what you truly are.